# YUI Compressor and PHPStorm

Tags: node.js, phpstorm

I'm trying to add a filewatcher in PHPStorm to automatically compress my js files. I followed [this tutorial](http://grafikkaos.co.uk/blog/article/119-using-filewatchers-in-phpstorm) but i have these errors:

```
cmd.exe /D /C C:/Users/Sofiane/node_modules/.bin/yuicompressor.cmd reglements.js >-o reglements.min.js

events.js:72
    throw er; // Unhandled 'error' event
          ^
Error: spawn ENOENT
at errnoException (child_process.js:1011:11)
at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (child_process.js:802:34)

Process finished with exit code 8
```

I don't really understand, it's the first time I use Node.js

Thanks for help !

Answer (score 4):

The error usually means that child_process.spawn threw ENOENT because the executable couldn't be found. Try adding a path to java.exe to your system PATH - does it help? Another solution is to specify a path to node_modules\yuicompressor\build\yuicompressor-2.4.8.jar as a program in file watchers (instead of yuicompressor.cmd)