# YUI Compressor gives Unhandled 'error' event in PhpStorm

Tags: node.js, phpstorm, yui-compressor

I try to setup YUI Compressor in PhpStorm. I have installed Node.js and config it in PhpStorm like the screenshot below. But when it runs it gives an "Unhandled 'error' event", see the other screenshot.

[image]

[image]

Comment: Possible duplicate of [YUI Compressor and PHPStorm](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28136813/yui-compressor-and-phpstorm)

Answer (score 7):

Found a solution from: [YUI Compressor and PHPStorm](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28136813/yui-compressor-and-phpstorm)

Changed the program path in the PhpStorm file watcher to:

C:\Users\Eric\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\yuicompressor\build\yuicompressor-2.4.8.jar

And works fine now!

Answer (score 1):

YUI Compressor needs JRE (Java runtime) to run - this error may also indicate that you don't have it installed.